# Objective-C (iOS) variable replacement in array values

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

How do I write `NSArray` values to utilize a variable similar to this `NSString`:

```
Levelname=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Background1Level%d.png",LevelNO];
    [backgroundimagview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:Levelname]];
```

Here is the code block I need to convert to use the LevelNO variable:

```
        [character setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"character1_09.png"]];
        character.animationImages=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"character1_01.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"character1_02.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"character1_03.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"character1_04.png"],nil ];
```

Comment: If The answer is correct please accept it so that other people can use it in the future

Answer (score 4):

loop through them with an integer and instead of "LevelNO" use that integer. Something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < {number of levels here}, i++)
{
  Levelname=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Background1Level%d.png",i];
  [myArray addObject:[UIImage imageWithName:Levelname];
}
```

Make sure to keep an array and replace myArray